# jqGrid filter is apllying but ui is not updated

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have two jqGrids and want to copy filter from the first to second. Filters are apllying and data is sorted, but ui does't correspond to that filter: i mean wront search options are displayed at column headers, incorrect search order arrow. So, the question is: How to update UI of jqGrid header to have correct header?

The code example is provided below:

```
var firstGridFilters = $("#firstjqGrid").getGridParam('postData').filters;
var secondGridParams = $("#secondjqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam');
secondGridParams.postData.filters = firstGridFilters;

$("#secondjqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', secondGridParams);
```

i was trying to update data like this:

```
$("#secondjqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

or

```
$("#secondjqGrid")[0].triggerToolbar();
```

The data is sorted but UI is wrong.

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS]() or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? The arrow of jqGrid header shows typically **the sorting order** and have no relation with the filter applied to jqGrid. Additionally, to apply the filter you need to set `search` option to `true` additionally to `postData.filters`. After that `$("#secondjqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');` will apply the new filter.

Comment: By the way, the line `$("#secondjqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', secondGridParams);` is unneeded because `$("#secondjqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam');` returns you **the reference** to the option object. You need just replace the line `$("#secondjqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', secondGridParams);` to `secondGridParams.search = true;` and then you can use `$("#secondjqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');`.

Comment: I'm using jqGrid 4.6.0. And we did't understand each other. The data in my grid is filtered and sorted correctly. BUT soper(^, ~, ==, etc.) and sort arrow is not updated in grid header. The problem with sort arrow is solved by calling sortGrid as you said. But the problem with soper remains (in the second grid data is filtered, but incorrect soper is shown). Is there are any ways to update layout of header grid?

Comment: Sorry, but you should *always* include the version of jqGrid, which you use especially if you use some retro version (more as 4 years old), which is not supported since many years. The problem, which you try to solve is a bug in the version 4.6. It's fixed in the later versions. No fixes for jqGrid 4.6 will be created.

Comment: Development of "jqGrid" is stopped at version 4.7. There are two main forks (follows) which are based on jqGrid 4.7 and has *another names*: 1) [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop and which can be used completely free of charge under MIT / GPL license (like jqGrid 4.6); 2) commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov. I recommend you to upgrade to the latest version of either "free jqGrid" or "Guriddo jqGrid JS".

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need to get all the parameters of the second grid set only one item and then put it back. The simple is to just set the filter of the second grid like this (sorry I do not test this)

The code example is provided below:

```
var firstGridFilters = $("#firstjqGrid").getGridParam('postData').filters;
$("#secondjqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {postData: { filters: firstGridFilters}});
```

Hope this will resolve the problem